# How to dynamically place images in a box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My html code is like this :

```
<input type='file' multiple/>
<br>

<?php
    for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {

?>
    <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>">

    </div>
<?php
    }
?>'
```

My javascript code is like this :

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
        for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
        }        
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
    $('#box0').append(imgTmpl);
};
```

Demo and full code is like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/85ip-hua2

I have 5 boxes

When the user uploads the image, the image will appear in the box

For example if user upload 2 image, then 2 image will appear in first box and second box

I've made the code. But my code can only put 1 image in the first box

I'm having trouble doing looping

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: $('#box0').append(imgTmpl); this will append images in box1 always, bcoz you box0 is the id for the first box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change you code like bellow to make it work:

```
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
        var IsImgAdded=false;
        $('.img-container').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('img').length==0 && IsImgAdded==false){
                $(this).append(imgTmpl);
                IsImgAdded=true;
            }
        });     
    };
```

Comment: Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674975/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button

Answer (score 1):

**Here is solutions with minor changes in your JS Code**,
It will image in every box,no matter how many boxes you have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var box_no=0;
    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
            for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
            }        
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        var box_id ='#box'+box_no+'';
        var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
        $(box_id).append(imgTmpl);
        box_no++;
    };

</script>
```

Cheer's

Answer (score 0):

If you alter the callback function to accept an additional parameter then perhaps you could do this

```
$(function () {
    $(":file").change(function () {
        var noOfFiles = this.files.length;
        for(var i=0; i < noOfFiles; i++) {        
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                imageIsLoaded.call( this, e, i );
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL( this.files[i] );
        }        
    });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e,i) {/* where i is the value from the file count */
    var imgTmpl = '<img height="142" width="162" src='+e.target.result+'>';
    /* use second parameter to get the relevant box id */
    $('#box'+i).append(imgTmpl);
};
```

One problem might be if a user uploaded more than 5 images ( if that is possible )

Comment: It does not fit. The result like this : https://postimg.org/image/6w1vfu529/. Should when I select 2 image, it will   display in box 1 and box 2