# How can I unify text that take from multiple group radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript code like this :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).parent().text();
        var $radio = $(this);
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
            $('#result-select').text('');
        }
        else{
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);
            $('#result-select').text(txt);
        }
        $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/m7by6zcw/21/

I want to :

If I select chelsea, madrid and juve the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve

If I select chelsea and madrid the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid

So if I check radio button, it display the text. If I uncheck radio button, it not display the text

How can I do it?

**Update** :

The radio button can be unchecked

For example :

If I select chelsea, madrid and juve the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve

Then I uncheck madrid, the result like this :

> Chelsea - Juve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m7by6zcw/37/

Basically like Justinas's answer but with the checking/unchecking available.

The only part I really changed was how the text was being outputted, shown below:

```
    let output = [];
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( function() {
            var txt = $(this).parent().text();
            output.push(txt);
    });
    $('#result-select').text(output.join(' - '));
```

You need to reset the data of everything else when something checks:

```
$(`input[name=${name}]:not(:checked)`).data('waschecked', false);
```

Comment: Great. It works. But there are still shortcomings. For example: you choose chelsea, then choose mu, then choose arsenal. Then choose chelsea again. When choosing chelsea again, it must click 2 times. Should be when select / click chelsea again, radio button directly selected without having to click 2 times

Comment: well, you didn't implement a reset for the non-checked stuff. I've updated.

Comment: Seems it works. But why it use `let`? If I change use `var`, Whether that's okay? Because in my project, if it use `let`, it will error

Comment: @samueltoh yeah just use var then. `let` is just block sensitive that's all. Just used let out of habit and forgot to change.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Btw, mark ` in not work in my project. Whether it can be without using a mark `?

Comment: Yes, just have to do the string concatenation the old fashion way: `"input[name="+name+"]:not(:checked)"`

Comment: Okay. Look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/m7by6zcw/39/. In my project the name like this : `name="league['england']"`. If the name like that, it not working. There exist error : `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=league['england']]:not(:checked)`

Comment: @samueltoh you need to quote them in this case so `\""+name+"\"` with the usual stuff before&after it

Comment: Like this : `var name = $(this).prop(\""+name+"\");` ? There exist error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: lol I guess I really have to spell it out. `$("input[name=\""+name+"\"]:not(:checked)")` Sorry I'm just too lazy with explaining sometimes

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824649/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button-and-multiple-gro

Answer (score 1):

You have to gather all values from `:checked` radio buttons, later use `.join` to convert array to string and place to results field

```js
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      var result = $('#result-select');
      var results = [];

      $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function () {
        results.push($(this).closest('label').text());
      });
      
      result.text(results.join(' - '));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Italy</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="italy" class="radio"> Juve
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="italy" class="radio"> Milan
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="italy" class="radio"> Inter
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<span id="result-select">Result</span>
```

Comment: In your code, once you check a radio button from some group (Italy for example), it'll always be checked and in the result it will be always a team from Italy !

Comment: @Justinas, Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824649/how-can-i-unify-text-that-take-from-multiple-group-radio-button-and-multiple-gro

Answer (score -1):

You need to first get the text value of the result : `var str = $('#result-select').text();`, then when you check a radio button, you just append the value to the result text `str += txt; $('#result-select').text(str);`.

And if you uncheck a radio button, you just replace it's value with an empty string `str = str.replace(txt,'');`.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).parent().text();
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
            var str = $('#result-select').text();
            str = str.replace(txt,'');
            $('#result-select').text(str);
        }
        else{
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);
            var str = $('#result-select').text();
            str += txt;
            $('#result-select').text(str);
        }

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Explain what have you changed.

Comment: Ah, ok, it was my bad, i did not understand what you wanted!! It's clearer for me now, good luck :)